# Adding any simple code to the old code causes Azure App restarts

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

We had a branch, **BRANCH-X** on UAT and Prod for a while now. When I deploy a new branch **BRANCH-Y** on UAT, the CPU utilization hits 100% and restarts the app as Azure Auto-heal is ON, which results in thousands of 503-Service Unavailable errors. Initially I thought my new changes would've caused this but when I look at the code, nothing seems to be the problem- functionality was good, all the exceptions are handled and no application exits.

For debugging if it's a code issue or something is happening internally, I made a small change to BRANCH-X and deployed on UAT. The change was a small as below-

Branch-X :

```
return 5;
```

New code on UAT for debugging:

```
int x = 5;
return x;
```

Now anyone would think the new code would work just like Branch-X, with no 503s. But that's not the case, the new code auto restarts, hits CPU 100% and throws 503s. To confirm, I again deployed BRANCH-X - No auto restarts, no 100% CPU and no 503s. I don't understand why any new code changes are giving me 503s on Azure. I have tried to browse for a good answer, but had no luck. So posting it here.

Comment: Time to run a profiler.

Comment: Or get a thread dump.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above suggestions, if you haven’t done this already, kindly leverage `Diagnose and Solve Problems` to fetch more details on `Web App Restarted`

I understand a simple code change is causing the restart and as you mentioned auto-heal is enabled.

You have mentioned about, BRANCH-X  and BRANCH-Y on UAT and Prod, if these are slots swaps.

To minimize these types of restarts, set the `WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG=1` app setting on all slots and see if it makes any difference.

Just to isolate the issue, you may try to use [proactive CPU monitoring](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/10/07/Mitigate-your-CPU-problems-before-they-even-happen.html) to set your own CPU threshold rules to temporarily mitigate a high CPU issue ( to narrow-down until the real cause for the issue is found)

Just to highlight, on the other hand, restarting an application could cause a possible increase in resource consumption, and depending on the application sometimes those extra resources can be high, so be aware that even though restarting a slot should not affect the other slots, resources are still shared, so it can indirectly affect the other slots if the App Service Plan does not have enough resources.

Most of the configuration changes trigger some sort of restart.

[App Service Restarts](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/09/16/App-Service-Restarts.html)  - This document covers some common operations that can be performed in an App Service and the effects in terms of availability and restart operations. Restarts on an App Service can be triggered either manually or by configuration changes.

Ref: [Troubleshoot swaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#troubleshoot-swaps)